# Objective-C Bridging Header for frameworks

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, bridging-header

I've made a framework that requires the sqlite3 framework. How do I add a Objective-C Bridging Header for my framework that imports sqlite3 into my Swift file?

I already have a bridging header file for my project, but not for my framework.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

<s>I found a `Objective-C Bridging Header` setting in the target Build Settings. It was hidden by default. Check All instead of Basic.</s>

In recent Xcode versions this solution would give the error `Using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported`.

The workaround I've been using is to make the C-header *public* in the file inspector and import it in `MyFramework.h` like this example:

```
#import <MyFramework/MyObjectiveC.h>
```

**How to change the C-header to *public***

Open your C-header and view the inspector by clicking in the upper right corner. To view the file inspector, click the file icon in the upper right corner.

[image]

Comment: This lead me to the error "using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported". The actual answer is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875745/xcode-6-beta-4-using-bridging-headers-with-framework-targets-is-unsupported.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to "make the C-header public in the file inspector" ?

Comment: Hi Gustaf, thanks for the quick reply. I'm trying to import an Objective C third party framework into my Swift framework and I get "no such module" error. I'm able to use that framework from objc code but not from swift code in the framework I'm creating. I know this could be a different question.

Comment: Sorry @Ravi, but I can't help you there. You can try checking the framework is linked in your target, I don't know anything more that will be to help.

Comment: @GustafRosenblad no problems and thanks for the reply. Since I'm able to use ObjC framework from an ObjC  .m file, I'm fine with it for now.

Comment: If set C-header to public, all Objective-C class will be visible outside of the framework. But I don'' want these Objective-C class to be exposed, what should I do?

Comment: @User9527 True. I had the same problem, but I have unfortunately not found a solution.

Comment: I found a solution for that. @GustafRosenblad , you need create xxx.modulemap,  set "Import Path" to import your modulemap. The modulemap file should look like: 
module OCModule [system] {
    header "System Services/SystemServices.h"
    header "networking/Reachability/Reachability.h"
    export *
}

Answer (score 3):

just import your sqlite3 framework in your objective-c bridging file. You then automatically can use it in Swift. 
 
**Apple Docs:**

> Interoperability is the ability to interface between Swift and Objective-C in either direction, letting you access and use pieces of code written in one language in a file of the other language. As you begin to integrate Swift into your app development workflow, it’s a good idea to understand how you can leverage interoperability to redefine, improve, and enhance the way you write Cocoa apps.
>   One important aspect of interoperability is that it lets you work with Objective-C APIs when writing Swift code. After you import an Objective-C framework, you can instantiate classes from it and interact with them using native Swift syntax.

**EDIT**: You even can import an Objective-C framework or Swift framework or a mixed-language framework just into your swift file with 
 
 `import yourFramework`

**Apple Docs:**

> Importing External Frameworks
>
> You can import external frameworks that have a pure Objective-C
>   codebase, a pure Swift codebase, or a mixed-language codebase. The
>   process for importing an external framework is the same whether the
>   framework is written in a single language or contains files from both
>   languages. When you import an external framework, make sure the
>   Defines Module build setting for the framework you’re importing is set
>   to Yes.
>
> You can import a framework into any Swift file within a different
>   target using the following syntax:

**SWIFT**

```
import FrameworkName
```

> You can import a framework into any Objective-C .m file within a
>   different target using the following syntax:

```
@import FrameworkName;
```

Comment: Using a bridging header is not allowed in Frameworks.
Following the above instructions in a framework will produce the above error upon building:

`error: using bridging headers with framework targets is unsupported`